# Silverlight 4 Capture source is not stopped

Tags: c#, silverlight, audio, silverlight-4.0

I am working on a Silverlight project to record the audio on a web page.

After I clicked the Pause button the code will always throw an exception:

**Capture source is not stopped**

If I put a break point on this line of code and wait there for 3-5 seconds then run the code, no exception will be threw.

```
    if (audioSink.CaptureSource.State == CaptureState.Started) (break point is on this line)
```

Here is the code

```
   private void Pause(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
        if (audioSink.CaptureSource.State == CaptureState.Started)
        {
            audioSink.CaptureSource.Stop();

            this.btnPause.IsEnabled = false;
            this.btnRecord.IsEnabled = true;
            this.btnSave.IsEnabled = true;
        }
    }

   audioSink.CaptureSource.Stop(); (This is the line of code which throws the exception)
```

Comment: That could be a security issue? Have you read the doc?

Comment: @lukas, as I mentioned in my post, this action can be done if I wait on the breakpoint for 3 to 5 seconds and then execute the rest of code.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it might help:

While using video source I tend to use [CaptureDeviceConfiguration.AllowDeviceAccess](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.capturedeviceconfiguration.alloweddeviceaccess%28v=vs.95%29) property  in order to check whether I can manipulate the capture object.

You can obtain the access to the device by calling [CaptureDeviceConfiguration.RequestDeviceAccess](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.capturedeviceconfiguration.requestdeviceaccess%28v=vs.95%29). You should be calling this method before calling the Start method of the capture. If you do this on the Start method, than you should already have the access and call the Stop method without having problems.

Comment: hi hoonzis, thank you for your reply. I did have that code to identify whether the web site has had the permission to get access to the web camera. It is the problem happening when I am trying to stop recording rather then starting.